# SQL Server state management login failed error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

One more observation - 
If I am trying to run service from local machine - I get message as 
**Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with trusted SQL Server connection.**

whereas,
If I run the service from server - it works fine.

## Any guess why ?

We are using SQL Server for session state management and as soon as we try to persist some object in the state manager DB - we get

> login failed error and multiple try eventually locks the AD
>   account.

1. What could be the reason as we are getting login failed error while storing object in session state manager?
2. Do we need to assign some access or privileges to our AD account ?

Our AD account has access to DB, I can login to SQL Server using my AD ID

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason, given that it eventually locks your ad account is that the password you are using is wrong, check windows security log on the DC, there will be a bunch of "Audit Failure" records that will give you more info.